# Losing scope in jQuery AJAX Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, lightbox

My lightbox opens and the new content is displayed within it.
But the script doesn't seem to add the event listener to the links in the generated content. Thus nothing happens but a new pageload.

```
var lightbox = (function() {
var init = function() {
    $('footer').append("<div id='lightbox'><div id='close'>x</div></div>");     
    $('#close').click(function() {
        $('#lightbox').hide();
        $('#lightbox').children(':not(#close)').remove();
    });
    ajax();
};
var ajax = function() {
    $('.ajax a').add('#lightbox a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#lightbox').children(':not(#close)').remove();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'), 
            success: function(result) {
                $('#lightbox').fadeIn(300).append(result);
        }});
    });
};
return {
    init:init
}
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually invoke `init` which is where your close handler is bound. `init` is a local variable which is never returned from your IIFE, so obviously it's not being invoked from outside this function.

The answer is to invoke `init`. As it stands, your `lightbox` function doesn't *do* anything except for declare (and then immediately discard) two variables named `init` and `ajax`.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add that `return { init:init }` in the snippet. But still only the `.ajax.a` links open in the lightbox. Links in the lightbox don't get opened in the lightbox.